# how to reduce the size of cross compiled shared libraries?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, cross-platform, zeromq, pyzmq

I am working on to install python3.6 along with zmq on a ARM based processor which has around 32 MB free space on the flash.

I have built python3.6 and removed the unwanted libraries, i have created python installation package with 15 MB and it is running fine for sample programs.

I need to install zmq to run my application, for that, i have cross compiled pyzmq for ARM as per the below link
https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/wiki/Cross-compiling-PyZMQ-for-Android
(this link is for android but i made modification as per my setup)

As expected, I have got the list of below libraries compiled for arm

```
2.6M    constants.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
3.0M    context.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
3.0M    _device.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
3.0M    error.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
3.1M    message.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
3.1M    _poll.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
3.1M    socket.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
3.0M    utils.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
3.0M    _version.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I need help on two problems here

1. The size of each library was around 20MB before strip. I was able to reduce them up to 3MB but i need to reduce it further more so as to accommodate on the flash. i have seen these libraries on other boards which are around 50KB each, so i believe there is a way to reduce the size of each library. can anyone please tell me, how can i do this?
2. The name of the files are not named as arm. however this is not a major problem for me as i can rename them manually but i need to know if i can change them during the build process.
   When i run the file command on these libraries, i can see they are built for arm.

> constants.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared
>   object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped

Below is my setup.cfg file i used for building pyzmq

```
[global]
# the prefix with which libzmq was configured / installed
zmq_prefix = /home/sagar/zmq/_install
have_sys_un_h = False

[build_ext]
libraries = python3.6
library_dirs = /home/sagar/python_source/arm_install_with_zmq/lib
include_dirs = /usr/include/python3.6m/
plat-name = linux-armv

[bdist_egg]
plat-name = linux-armv
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got one of the solution for my problem.